# How to import only certain rows from one Access database to another?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to import a row of data from one Access database to another. I don't want to import the entire table, only specified rows. I have code that works right now, however it is rather clunky and I feel like there must be a better way:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim importRs As DAO.Recordset
Dim destRs As DAO.Recordset
Dim importDb As Database
Dim destDb As Database

Set importDb = OpenDatabase(filepath)
Set destDb = CurrentDb

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblAO WHERE AOID = " & AOID
Set importRs = importDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblAO VALUES(" & importRs.Fields("AOID").Value & ", '" & importRs.Fields("AOName") & "' , '" & importRs.Fields("Description") & "' ," & importRs.Fields("Default") & "," & importRs.Fields("MILCON").Value & "," & importRs.Fields("SUST").Value & ")"
destDb.Execute strSQL
```

Is there any way to import the entire row of data cleanly? Or a better way to import multiple rows besides looping though each one? I have other data to import that has many columns and multiple rows, and I don't want my code getting slow or hard to read. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/458683-select-data-other-db

Comment: Both tables are called `tblAO` and are Access tables?

Comment: Yes, they are the same table but in different versions of our database.

Comment: You could import the table as a linked table and then use a normal SQL statement to move data across.  Something like:  `INSERT INTO tblAO_In_This_Database SELECT * FROM tblAO_Linked_From_Other_Database WHERE ID IN (1,4)`

Comment: The `WHERE` clause could be anything then - `WHERE Default = TRUE` for example.

Comment: Thanks both of you! I used the method @Nathan_Sav suggested and it worked.